# lineheight too big for textwrap/autoHeight

Tags: ag-grid

The data I want to display in ag-grid is predominantly blocks of text.  I would like the text to wrap and the cell height to auto.

```
   wrapText: true,
   autoHeight: true
```

However, when the text wraps, it maintains a line-height of 40px, which is not attractive. I also notice it doesn't try to wrap on word.

I tried resetting the line-height, but then I lose any top or bottom padding.  When I add the padding, the top padding is fine, but the bottom padding is hidden - the row height does not account for the padding.

How do I get an attractive block text display in a cell with decent padding of the cell contents?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add some CSS to directly target the cell content to add padding:

```
.ag-theme-alpine .ag-cell-value {
  line-height: 20px !important;
  word-break: normal; /* prevent words from breaking */
  padding-top: 5px; /* space top */
  padding-bottom: 5px; /* space bottom */
}
```

See this implemented in the [following plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/uyW1AogzaYU4jU0n?preview)

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!  exactly what I needed

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to fix the word wrapping, but AG Grid provides css options for customizing the styling of the line height. e.g.

```
.ag-theme-alpine.ag-custom {
  --ag-grid-size: 3px;
  --ag-list-item-height: 20px;
}
```

See https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/global-style-customisation-compactness/ for more information.